# How can I get the projection of some fields of a specific document embedded in an array?

Tags: mongodb

Consider the following (simplified) example:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: "Andrew",
  role: "ATT",
  Sesons: [
            {
             year: "2018-2019",
             age: 20,
             goals: 10
             }, 
             {
             year: "2019-2020",
             age: 21,
             goals: 101
             }]
}
{
  _id: 2,
  name: "Paul",
  role: "DF",
  Sesons: [
            {
             year: "2018-2019",
             age: 15,
             goals: 102
             }, 
             {
             year: "2019-2020",
             age: 16,
             goals: 1
             }]
}
```

How can I get this specific result from a query, based on {"Seasons.year": "2019-2020"} for example ?

```
{_id: 2, name: "Paul", role: "DF", Seasons: {age: 16}}
```

And how can I get this result from a query by getting an entire embedded document?

```
{_id: 2, name: "Paul", role: "DF", Seasons: {year: "2018-2019", age: 16, goals: 1}}
```

Thank you so much!
I apologize for the question, perhaps, not correctly formatted, but it is my first question about Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).You can query like following.

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": 2
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      role: 1,
      Sesons: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$Sesons",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.year",
              "2019-2020"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y10m2Nveqf0) . Once you get your result, again use the `$project` to get only age with other fields. Eg :

```
{
    $project: {
      "Sesons.year": 0,
      "Sesons.goals": 0
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I have more fields in embedded document, so do I have to set all fields to 0 in the query? Or are they the ones I need at 1?

Comment: 0 - to exclude the field, 1 - to include the field. Its easy if u go through the document

Comment: Retrying the query you wrote on another collection ( [link] (https://mongoplayground.net/p/8RMlWXXcahD) [link] ) , how come I get "season": [ ]? And not the filtered document?

Comment: I dont get ur question, if its a new type of question, please do create a new question, ans comment the link